# How to wrap the returns of method to one div block

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating like model in rails application. To use images in tooltip I need to wrap them all to:

```
<div class="tooltip">
```

The main method is:

```
  def like_user_avatars
    likes.map(&:user_avatar).map { |avatar| image_tag(avatar,
    class: "tooltip_avatars") }.join
  end
```

It generate something like this: `<img src='...'><img src='...>`. I need to wrap them all to one div block named tooltip, it should looks like  `<div class="tooltip"><img src='...'><img src='...></div>.`
**I tried to add content tag :div, class: "tooltip"**, but it doesn't wrap everything. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concat` to combine all images and wrap them into parent `div`

```
def like_user_avatars
  content_tag :div, class: 'tooltip' do
    likes.each do |like| 
      concat image_tag(like.user_avatar.avatar, class: "tooltip_avatars")
    end
  end
end
```

[More about `contact` and his usage](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat)

Comment: Yes, except the div should wrap all likes, not a single like.

Comment: @AlexKojin ***undefined method `output_buffer=' for #<BonusDecorator:0x007fa67faf1d38>*** on content_tag string

Comment: It works with standard rails helper. What's decorator gem?

Comment: If you use drapper decorator gem when change `content_tag` to `h.content_tag`